# Implementing Moving Graphics from Computational Software Packages

Tags: graphics, matlab, wolfram-mathematica

I know that you can implement movies into your LaTeX document, but I wanted to know is there a way to implement moving graphics after source code is compiled in Matlab?

This questions can really become a wiki and can be broadened to other systems such as: 
Maple, Mathematica, and so on.

Comment: Which kind (file format) of graphics do you have in mind?

Comment: Not quite sure, I have a `.m` file, and I have written up some code and plotted the results all with a **for** loop. So, the plots are constantly being updated with array values and this makes the plots moves in the figure window when the file is ran until the array within the **for** loop has reached the max value.  How could I get the graphics to move with the same behavior in a (La)Tex document. Maybe for a better visualization, here is a example of what the graphics do below. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convolution

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [`animate`](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/animate) package should do the job. It is assumed that the PDF frames are inside one big PDF document, one frame per page. Here is an example:

```
% playing at 12 frames per second
\animategraphics{12}{name-of-animation-pdf-file}{}{}
```

There is a dedicated [tutorial](http://www.texample.net/tikz/examples/animated-set-intersection/) showing how to include a series of PDF frames generated by any software including Matlab. The tutorial is targeted to graphics produced by [TikZ](http://www.texample.net/tikz/) using an intermediate PDF file.

There are some nice [examples](http://www.texample.net/tikz/examples/tag/animations/) that show animated plots drawn by TikZ, including one that demonstrates [convolution](http://www.texample.net/tikz/examples/convolution-of-two-functions/).