# pgfplot ; animate ; pythontex : a plot of a derivative

Tags: tikz-pgf, animate, pythontex

With the BIG help of @njsg (Nuno Silva) I made this plot.
The goal is use it as a animation inside a beamer slide.

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=newest}
\usepackage[export]{animate}
%\usepackage{animate}
\usepackage{pythontex}
\usepackage[output-decimal-marker={,}]{siunitx}

% Código copiado de
% https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/389478/how-can-i-access-a-float-defined-via-pgfmathsetmacro-from-pythontex/389530#389530
\makeatletter
\newcommand{\pythontexassign}[2]{%
  \expandafter\pythontexassign@i\expandafter{#2}{#1}}
\newcommand{\pythontexassign@i}[2]{%
  \pyc{#2=#1}}
\makeatother
% 

\newcommand{\pySI}[2]{\py{'\SI{' + str(#1) + '}{#2}'}} 

\begin{document}

\begin{pycode}
#!/usr/bin/env python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
from sympy import *

x       =   symbols('x')

xp      =   1
func    =   x**2+2
Deltax  =   9
Divisoes=   10
dx      =   Deltax/Divisoes

func    =   sympify(func)
dfunc   =   diff(func, x)

yp      =   func.subs(x,xp)
mt      =   dfunc.subs(x,xp)
bt      =   yp-mt*xp
tang    =   mt*x+bt
tang    =   sympify(tang)

def sympy2pgf(expression):
    return latex(expression,mul_symbol='times')\
        .replace(r'\times','*')\
            .replace('{','(').replace('}',')')

def teste(valor):
    return valor

def calcpos(i):
    xi  =   (xp+Deltax) - dx*i
    yi  =   func.subs(x,xi)
    return(xi,yi)

def recta(i):
    if xp == (xp+Deltax) - dx*i:
        return sympy2pgf(tang)
    else:
        ms   = (calcpos(i)[1] - yp)/(calcpos(i)[0] - xp)
        bs   = yp - ms*xp
        seca = ms*x+bs
        seca = sympify(seca)
        return sympy2pgf(seca)
\end{pycode}

\begin{animateinline}[poster=last,autoplay,loop]{5} 
\multiframe{10}{rt=1+1}{% 
\resizebox{0.5\textwidth}{!}{%
\begin{tikzpicture}[shift={(1,1)},x=1cm, y=1cm,
    extended line/.style={shorten >=-#1,shorten <=-#1},
    extended line/.default=2cm]
\begin{axis}[% 
    x=1cm, y=0.1cm,
    anchor=target,
    enlargelimits=0.05,
    axis x line = center,
    axis y line = left,
    axis line style={line width=1pt,->,opacity=1},
    ymin=0,
    ymax=120,
    xmin=0,
    xmax=12,
    clip mode=individual,
    %clip mode=false,
    axis x line=bottom,
    axis y line=left,
    xtick={0,2,...,10},
    ytick={0,20,...,100},
    ticklabel style={font=\normalsize,opacity=1},
    xlabel={$t/\si{s}$},
    ylabel={$x/\si{m}$},
    y tick label style={
        /pgf/number format/.cd,
        fixed,
        fixed zerofill,
        precision=1,
        use comma,
        /tikz/.cd},
    x tick label style={
        /pgf/number format/.cd,
        fixed,
        fixed zerofill,
        precision=1,
        use comma,
        /tikz/.cd},
    every axis x label/.style={
        at={(ticklabel* cs:1)},
        anchor=north east,
        style={font=\normalsize},
        opacity=1},
    every axis y label/.style={
        at={(ticklabel* cs:1)},
        anchor=north east,
        style={font=\normalsize},
        opacity=1},
    %ticks=none,
]

% Atribuição da variável \rt a meurt
\pythontexassign{meurt}{\rt}

% curva
\pys{\addplot [domain=0:10, samples=100, color=blue ]{!{sympy2pgf(func)}};}

% rectas 
\pys{\addplot [domain=0:10, samples=100, color=blue ]{!{recta(meurt)}};}

% Ponto fixo
\pys{\coordinate (P) at  (!{xp},!{yp});}
\node[outer sep=0pt,circle, fill=red,inner sep=1.5pt] (P) at (P) {};

% Ponto variável
\pys{\coordinate (Q) at  (!{calcpos(meurt)[0]},!{calcpos(meurt)[1]});}
\node[outer sep=0pt,circle, fill=red,inner sep=1.5pt] (Q) at (Q) {};

% tracejados
\pys{\draw[red,dotted,very thick] (P) -- (!{xp},0);}
\pys{\draw[red,dotted,very thick] (P) -- (0,!{yp});}
\pys{\draw[red,dotted,very thick] (Q) -- (!{calcpos(meurt)[0]},0);}
\pys{\draw[red,dotted,very thick] (Q) -- (0,!{calcpos(meurt)[1]});}

% chavetas
\pys{\draw[decorate,decoration={brace,amplitude=3pt,mirror}] (!{xp},-5.0) -- (!{calcpos(meurt)[0]},-5.0) ; }
\pys{\draw[decorate,decoration={brace,amplitude=3pt,mirror}] (-.90,!{calcpos(meurt)[1]}) -- (-.90,!{yp}) ; }

% Deltas
\pys{\pgfmathsetmacro\XP{!{xp}}}
\pys{\pgfmathsetmacro\YP{!{yp}}}
\pys{\pgfmathsetmacro\XI{!{calcpos(meurt)[0]}}}
\pys{\pgfmathsetmacro\YI{!{calcpos(meurt)[1]}}}
\pgfmathsetmacro\DELTAX{ \XI - \XP }
\pgfmathsetmacro\DELTAY{ \YI - \YP }
\node[text width=3cm] at (\XI,-10.0) {$\Delta x =$ \DELTAX $\si{\second}$};
\node[text width=3cm] at (-1.55,\YI) {$\Delta y =$ \DELTAY $\si{\metre}$ };

\node[coordinate] (target) at (axis cs:0,0){};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}}}
\end{animateinline}

\end{document}
```

But, when I change from this

```
\usepackage[export]{animate}
%\usepackage{animate}
```

to this

```
%\usepackage[export]{animate}
\usepackage{animate}
```

the result is unexpected, as the images show

[image]

and the next one, the problematic:

[image]

what I can do to solve this issue.

---

To AlexG

1. compile de next code with:

xelatex figura.tex
pythontex figura.
xelatex figura.tex

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=newest}
\usepackage[export]{animate}
%\usepackage{animate}
\usepackage{pythontex}
\usepackage[output-decimal-marker={,}]{siunitx}

% Código copiado de
% https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/389478/how-can-i-access-a-float-defined-via-pgfmathsetmacro-from-pythontex/389530#389530
\makeatletter
\newcommand{\pythontexassign}[2]{%
  \expandafter\pythontexassign@i\expandafter{#2}{#1}}
\newcommand{\pythontexassign@i}[2]{%
  \pyc{#2=#1}}
\makeatother
% 

\newcommand{\pySI}[2]{\py{'\SI{' + str(#1) + '}{#2}'}} 

\begin{document}

\begin{pycode}
#!/usr/bin/env python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
from sympy import *

x       =   symbols('x')

xp      =   1
func    =   x**2+2
Deltax  =   9
Divisoes=   10
dx      =   Deltax/Divisoes

func    =   sympify(func)
dfunc   =   diff(func, x)

yp      =   func.subs(x,xp)
mt      =   dfunc.subs(x,xp)
bt      =   yp-mt*xp
tang    =   mt*x+bt
tang    =   sympify(tang)

def sympy2pgf(expression):
    return latex(expression,mul_symbol='times')\
        .replace(r'\times','*')\
            .replace('{','(').replace('}',')')

def teste(valor):
    return valor

def calcpos(i):
    xi  =   (xp+Deltax) - dx*i
    yi  =   func.subs(x,xi)
    return(xi,yi)

def recta(i):
    if xp == (xp+Deltax) - dx*i:
        return sympy2pgf(tang)
    else:
        ms   = (calcpos(i)[1] - yp)/(calcpos(i)[0] - xp)
        bs   = yp - ms*xp
        seca = ms*x+bs
        seca = sympify(seca)
        return sympy2pgf(seca)
\end{pycode}

\begin{animateinline}[poster=first,autoplay,loop]{4} 
\multiframe{10}{rt=1+1}{% 
\resizebox{0.5\textwidth}{!}{%
\begin{tikzpicture}[shift={(1,1)},x=1cm, y=1cm,
    extended line/.style={shorten >=-#1,shorten <=-#1},
    extended line/.default=2cm]
\begin{axis}[% 
    x=1cm, y=0.1cm,
    anchor=target,
    enlargelimits=0.05,
    axis x line = center,
    axis y line = left,
    axis line style={line width=1pt,->,opacity=1},
    ymin=0,
    ymax=120,
    xmin=0,
    xmax=12,
    clip mode=individual,
    axis x line=bottom,
    axis y line=left,
    xtick={0,2,...,10},
    ytick={0,20,...,100},
    ticklabel style={font=\normalsize,opacity=1},
    xlabel={$t/\si{s}$},
    ylabel={$x/\si{m}$},
    y tick label style={
        /pgf/number format/.cd,
        fixed,
        fixed zerofill,
        precision=1,
        use comma,
        /tikz/.cd},
    x tick label style={
        /pgf/number format/.cd,
        fixed,
        fixed zerofill,
        precision=1,
        use comma,
        /tikz/.cd},
    every axis x label/.style={
        at={(ticklabel* cs:1)},
        anchor=north east,
        style={font=\normalsize},
        opacity=1},
    every axis y label/.style={
        at={(ticklabel* cs:1)},
        anchor=north east,
        style={font=\normalsize},
        opacity=1},
]

% Atribuição da variável \rt a meurt
\pythontexassign{meurt}{\rt}

% curva
\pys{\addplot [domain=0:10, samples=100, color=blue ]{!{sympy2pgf(func)}};}

% rectas 
\pys{\addplot [domain=0:10, samples=100, color=blue ]{!{recta(meurt)}};}

% Ponto fixo
\pys{\coordinate (P) at  (!{xp},!{yp});}
\node[outer sep=0pt,circle, fill=red,inner sep=1.5pt] (P) at (P) {};

% Ponto variável
\pys{\coordinate (Q) at  (!{calcpos(meurt)[0]},!{calcpos(meurt)[1]});}
\node[outer sep=0pt,circle, fill=red,inner sep=1.5pt] (Q) at (Q) {};

% tracejados
\pys{\draw[red,dotted,very thick] (P) -- (!{xp},0);}
\pys{\draw[red,dotted,very thick] (P) -- (0,!{yp});}
\pys{\draw[red,dotted,very thick] (Q) -- (!{calcpos(meurt)[0]},0);}
\pys{\draw[red,dotted,very thick] (Q) -- (0,!{calcpos(meurt)[1]});}

% chavetas
\pys{\draw[decorate,decoration={brace,amplitude=3pt,mirror}] (!{xp},-5.0) -- (!{calcpos(meurt)[0]},-5.0) ; }
\pys{\draw[decorate,decoration={brace,amplitude=3pt,mirror}] (-.90,!{calcpos(meurt)[1]}) -- (-.90,!{yp}) ; }

% Deltas
% inicialização
\pgfmathsetmacro\XP{0.0}
\pgfmathsetmacro\YP{0.0}
\pgfmathsetmacro\XI{0.0}
\pgfmathsetmacro\YI{0.0}
% operação
\pys{\pgfmathsetmacro\XP{!{xp}}}
\pys{\pgfmathsetmacro\YP{!{yp}}}
\pys{\pgfmathsetmacro\XI{!{calcpos(meurt)[0]}}}
\pys{\pgfmathsetmacro\YI{!{calcpos(meurt)[1]}}}
\pgfmathsetmacro\DELTAX{ \XI - \XP }
\pgfmathsetmacro\DELTAY{ \YI - \YP }
\node[text width=3cm] at (\XI,-10.0) {$\Delta x =$ \DELTAX $\si{\second}$};
\node[text width=3cm] at (-1.55,\YI) {$\Delta y =$ \DELTAY $\si{\metre}$ };

\node[coordinate] (target) at (axis cs:0,0){};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}}}
\end{animateinline}

\end{document}
```

you have just make a pdf with the name figura.pdf

2. then, compile the next code with

xelatex beamer.tex

```
\documentclass[compress]{beamer}
\usepackage{animate}

\begin{document}
\section{Figura}
\begin{frame}
\begin{figure}
\animategraphics[autoplay,loop]{4}{figura}{}{}
\end{figure}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Works for me.

[image]

Comment: The issue I get is `Undefined control sequence \XI`, to get it to work I had to comment out the four lines starting with `\pgfmathsetmacro\DELTAX{ \XI - \XP }`, run `pdflatex` then `pythontex`, then uncomment those four lines, and run `pdflatex` again. I don't quite understand what the problem is though, is there a lot of whitespace in the second image? Edit: that was without changing the code at all though.

Comment: `\XI` is being defined inside `\pys{}`, which means it will not be defined until there is some result from pythontex to embed in the document. Either all uses of `\XI` need to be wrapped with `\pys` or `pysub` (while this looks like it is possible here, it might not be always possible), or `\XI` must be defined in some way outside pythontex (for example, by adding `\pgfmathsetmacro\XI{42}` (or some other value, of course) before the `\pys{...}` command which will set `\XI` — somebody else might have a more elegant solution, though?).

Comment: @TorbjørnT., thankyou!
the pdf comes very large, with the graphic on right side.

Comment: @njsg
still the same as before.

% Deltas

% inicialização

\pgfmathsetmacro\XP{0.0}

\pgfmathsetmacro\YP{0.0}

\pgfmathsetmacro\XI{0.0}

\pgfmathsetmacro\YI{0.0}

% operação

\pys{\pgfmathsetmacro\XP{!{xp}}}

\pys{\pgfmathsetmacro\YP{!{yp}}}

\pys{\pgfmathsetmacro\XI{!{calcpos(meurt)[0]}}}

\pys{\pgfmathsetmacro\YI{!{calcpos(meurt)[1]}}}

\pgfmathsetmacro\DELTAX{ \XI - \XP}

\pgfmathsetmacro\DELTAY{ \YI - \YP}

\node[text width=3cm] at (\XI,-10.0) {$\Delta x =$ \DELTAX $\si{\second}$};

\node[text width=3cm] at (-1.55,\YI) {$\Delta y =$ \DELTAY $\si{\metre}$ };

Comment: Forgot to mention one thing: the `P` and `Q` nodes are defined within a `\pys`, so at the first run they are not available, and you get an error. Do as @njsg suggest, and use a `\pys` for those two `\node`s as well. Doesn't solve the whitespace problem, but it would make the code compile without errors.

Comment: That said, given that you want to make an animation, I don't really understand why you don't want the `export` option in the first place.

Comment: @TorbjørnT., if I understand `animate` correctly, `export` exports the animation with the still frames as different pages, while, without that option, it is exported as a PDF embedded animation.

Comment: @TorbjørnT. because I need the embedded animation to use it in a Beamer presentation.

Comment: In theory if you create a multi-page PDF called `foo.pdf`, you could load the `animate` package in your presentation and use `\animategraphics{2}{foo}{}{}` to get an animation running at 2 fps (cf. https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/30683/). I couldn't get it to work, but I don't know if it's because the PDF viewers I tried couldn't handle the animation.

Comment: @TorbjørnT.
Thank you. I've follow your advice and works! :-)

Comment: @njsg - Thank you, Nuno, for your knowledge and patience. :-)

Comment: So, how did you get those plots in your question when the code you posted does not compile? Put the code you really used and the required compilation steps in your question.

Comment: @AlexG : I've edited the post.

Comment: The first `xelatex` already fails. `! Package pgf Error: No shape named P is known.`

Comment: @AlexG - I don't what to say. Try with pdflatex in the same way.

Comment: @AlexG only a compilation without input from pythontex fails. If you let it run despite the errors (hit return a couple times, or use `xelatex -interaction nonstopmode`, for example), you should be able to run pythontex and latex itself won't fail anymore after that.

Comment: Chances are that, at some point, P and Q were defined outside pythontex commands, or were only used inside pythontex commands. From there, it'd be easy to end up with a document that gives these errors if compiled from scratch.

Comment: By the way, the whitespace issue disappears if the `preview` option is passed to the document class. But that will also change the output of `animate` with the `export` option.

Comment: @njsg It looks as though the whitespace is produced by the python calls. I wonder why Python is used at all. The analytical expression for the derivative is easily found. It allows you to calculate the intersection points of the secant line with the curve without the need for an external program.

Comment: @AlexG : Well... make your proposal, I've done mine, using pythontex. And I like it! :-)

Comment: @AlexG So far this is looking like an issue between pythontex and standalone, similar to [[1](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/399666/standalone-package-with-pythontex-and-tikz-how-to-avoid-space-around-picture)] and [[2](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/82589/why-is-there-extra-whitespace-to-the-left-of-this-standalone-document-when-using)].

Comment: I was able to reproduce this with a minimal example that has standalone and pythontex. Seems to be related to the pygments feature, as the issue does not show up when I compile it from scratch with the `pygments=false` option of pythontex.

Comment: This is enough to reproduce: `\documentclass{standalone}\usepackage{pythontex}\begin{document}Teste: \py{'1'}\end{document}`